# Is there a standard set of statistics to apply to benchmark data?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, software

I'm writing a web application that takes benchmark data from our in-development video game. Here is a preview of one of the benchmarks:
[image]

We intend to run and collect this data once per day or more. We don't need this level of detail and the questions we want to answer with this are:

1. What changes are there between benchmark runs?
2. Flag any large deviations.

I'm thinking I'll need to take each benchmark and average out the samples to much fewer samples, as well as calculate things like standard dev, median, etc.

My question here is: Is there a standard set of stats I should be applying here? For example, if I averaged each benckmark stat down to 1 sample, it'd lose a lot of information like the peak at the start. Would recording the min and max for the benchmark session but sufficient?